# Getting build errors on Theme attributes

Tags: android, themes

I want to change the values of a couple attributes in Theme.

I've looked at the file /platforms/android-15/data/res/themes.xml and found these attributes in the definition of Theme --

```
    <item name="android:panelMenuIsCompact">false</item>
    <item name="android:panelMenuListWidth">296dip</item>
```

Yes, my manifest has --

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

In my styles.xml file I've added --

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:panelMenuIsCompact">false</item>
    <item name="android:panelMenuListWidth">296dip</item>
</style>
```

when I build, the  lines get the errors --

```
 No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:panelMenuIsCompact'.
 No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:panelMenuListWidth'.
```

We know these are valid attributes, since they are in the theme definition, and they are also in the file attrs.xml, in the same directory as themes.xml.  So what is the problem?

Comment: Is your parent for your style correct? I mean is this correct : parent="@android:style/Theme. Or it should be just "android:Theme

Answer (score 1):

Those attributes are not specified in Android's public.xml, so you won't be able to use them. You can either take a look in your local /platforms/android-15/data/res/values/public.xml or else you can look at the online documentation for 
[android.R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you see, those attrs are defined in Themes.xml. So your parent should be:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:panelMenuIsCompact">false</item>
    <item name="android:panelMenuListWidth">296dip</item>
</style>
```